# Error with IB Designables in Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, autolayout, ibdesignable

/Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for ViewController ...
  Reason: image not found

[image]

Anyone know what is the problem ?

Comment: use custom xibs ???

Comment: I use CountryPickerSwift library which contain .xib file

Comment: it's name is countryPicker ????

Comment: Yes ...........

Comment: open the xib file and from Identity and Type panel un check 'Use Trait Variations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem always happens with xibs , so open the xib file related and from Identity and Type panel un check **Use Trait Variations**

[image]